# Adding a text expression to xy plot, automatic location

Tags: r

The siAll, this is a follow up to muy question from yesterday. Below I tried to add a link

[prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329626/using-dataframe-column-names-as-chart-label-in-apply)

the latest code is:

```
mypanel <- function(x,y,...) {
  panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
  panel.grid(x=-1, y=-1)
  panel.lmline(x,y,col="red",lwd=1,lty=1)
  panel.text(200,20,bquote(rho == .(correls[x])),cex=.8, font = 2,col="black")
} 

correls <- as.vector(cor(x=mtcars[,2:3],y=mtcars[,1]))
correls<- round(coeff,3)
names(correls)<-names(mtcars[,2:3])

data <- mtcars[,2:3]
charts <- lapply(names(data), function(x) { xyplot (mtcars[,1] ~ mtcars[,x], 
                                                    panel=mypanel,ylab="MPG", xlab=x)})
```

The code requires the datset mtcars as well as lattice and I think it may need LtticeExtra s well.

As you can see I calculated the correaltion coefficients and want to add them to the chart. The text gest added but there are 2 problems:

1. The part correls[x] is not evaluating as I wanted, I get an NA (it works by itself in the console though,I always check that to find errors). I do not seem to know how to fix that,even a pointer would help, I am happy to do the leg work
2. In some charts the coordinates do not work, since this is running in lapply that means some are not visible Inthis case not n the first charts, yes on the second). Is it possible to have the location be automatic? Agin just a pointer to what to look for or use is appreciated

Thanks again

Mario

Update, the solution suggested with panel number does snot work, each chart is created individually by lapply so it is always 1 so I do not get what I need. I modified the code to try o deal with the placement and the starting coordinates. However it does not always showand it also shows the wrong element from correl for some reason, to see that oneneeds to manually print charts using charts[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329626/using-dataframe-column-names-as-chart-label-in-apply), etc.

here is latest code

```
mypanel <- function(x,y,...) {
  panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
  panel.grid(x=-1, y=-1)
  panel.lmline(x,y,col="red",lwd=1,lty=1)
  panel.text(xmax[x],ymax,bquote(rho == .(correls[x])),pos=4,cex=1, font = 2,col="black")
} 

correls <- as.vector(cor(x=mtcars[,2:10],y=mtcars[,1]))
correls<- round(correls,3)
names(correls)<-names(mtcars[,2:10])
xmax <-sapply(mtcars[,2:10],max)
names(xmax) <- names(mtcars[,2:10])
xmax<-floor(xmax)
ymax <- floor(max(mtcars[,1]))


data <- mtcars[,2:10]
charts <- lapply(names(data), function(x) { xyplot (mtcars[,1] ~ mtcars[,x], 
                                                    panel=mypanel,ylab="MPG", xlab=x,
                                                    xlim=c(0,ceiling(max(mtcars[,x])))
                                                  ,ylim=c(0,ceiling(max(mtcars[,1]))))})
```

thanks again for any pointers

Mario

Comment: Is part of this due to not noticing that you have "coeff" instead of "correls" in that `round` call? Other than that there are functions in Lattice that let you tell which panel you are working with. That would be the way to build the index to access the correct `correls` values.

Comment: thanks for catching that - while that would create an incorrect value of course (I wil lcorreect it) that is not the problem. correls has values in it, the value is not being picked up in the label. A label is placed in the correct one the rho and equal sign display but the correl[x] evaluates to NA so I see rho = NA (with row in greek letters of course)
The other question is how if at all can I have the lable place in the visible area, as the coordinates are different enough that they sometikmes do not display. Can that be done? i there an R function that can place the label automatically?

Comment: Exactly. That was my point about changing the manner in which you indexed the `correls` vector.

Comment: Part of the problem is undoubtedly due to multiple uses of "x", but I cannot figure out how to get bquote or substitute to accept `correls[x]` if I change the name of the passed column name.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Couldn't get it to work. The `charts` object is a list and it should be possible to add the elements to it. There have been some recent questions on SO that demonstrated that process. Try searching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will search SO in detail. My latest idea is to move the text to be part of the function called on lappet and not the panelxy, that cold fix the x issue - at least is is worth a try

Comment: I am providing an update, I stopped trying with lattice. I think it can be done with base graphs in a function, but then I discovered ggplot2, it has better functionality (imho) and the charts look much nicer to me. I can just generate my charts In a loop and then use multiplot to create the lattice. I will come back and post my solution, but there are plenty of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, I used the function multiplot I found and ggplot2, mostly because it made more sense to me (its syntax) and because I like the look of its charts.

Here is the entire code, including the multiplot function that I found on "Cookbook for R" (many thanks).

this can be further improved as now I need to rename the dataset used as my data. I realize I could enclose all of that in a function, but for now this is not too much trouble for me.

I hope this helps someone.

Finally, I would say that I am not so happy about the text placement, ideally it would seek empty space but I guess that would not be so easy. If someone knows how feel free to share.

```
#You need to create an object called my data with your data.frame
#the process will create charts of correlations for the first column versus all others
#and then arrange them in a lattice patter.
#It uses the multiplot function that I found as well as ggplot2

mydata<-mtcars

library(ggplot2)
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  require(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
    # ncol: Number of columns of plots
    # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                     ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

  if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                      layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

mychart <- function(x) {
  c <- round(cor(mydata[,1],mydata[x]),3)
  xmax <-ceiling(max(mydata[,x]))
  xmin <- floor(min(mydata[,x]))
  xpos = floor(max(mydata[,x])*(8/10))
  ypos = floor(max(mydata[,1])*(8/10))
  t = paste("rho ==",c,sep="")
  t1 <- annotate("text",x=xpos,y=ypos,label=t,parse=TRUE,color="red")
  p <- qplot(mydata[,x],mydata[,1],xlab=x,ylab=names(mydata)[1],color=I("blue"))
  s <- stat_smooth(aes(x=mydata[,x],y=mydata[,1]),method="lm",color="red",se=FALSE)
  a <- annotate("text",x=xpos,y=ypos,label=t,parse=TRUE,color="red")
  p<- p+s+a+xlim(xmin,xmax)

}


charts <- NULL
l1 <- NULL
for (i in 2:(length(mydata))) {
  charts[[i]]<- mychart(names(mydata)[i])
}

numcols <- ceiling(sqrt(length(mydata)-1))

multiplot(plotlist=charts[2:length(mydata)],cols=numcols)
```